# Connect html button to open link in another tab

Tags: html, hyperlink

Good night, if i click on this html link, it does what is expected, jumps to another tab and downloads the file.

```
<a href="https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/eb48d7ab-a64a-4b99-b59d-72a34da60076/downloads/Calculator.zip?ver=1621722035246" download rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Download Calculator</a>
```

But when trying to connect the button to a link so that it opens in another tab (a jump link) I can't get it to do so, so far (and after several attempts) this is what i have, i appreciate help to see where i'm failing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.btn {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn" onclick=" window.open('https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/eb48d7ab-a64a-4b99-b59d-72a34da60076/downloads/Calculator.zip?ver=1621722035246','_blank');return false;">Download</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want it to open a tab in web or a tab you're working on

Comment: Both the link and button work identically in firefox.

Comment: I want it to open on the web, in a new tab

Comment: Hi Asis, forget to mention that it is Chrome where it does not work

Comment: @AlexisOmar if i'm not wrong, you're opening a zip file which directly downloands right?i tried it in chrome and it gets downloaded

Comment: target="_blank" makes the link get opened in new link but yours is a zip file to downloand

Comment: @Hanaa Is it downloaded through the second code? as is how is it?

Comment: @AlexisOmar it gets downloaded with both codes that I answered with

Answer (score 0):

however here is how to do it:

```
<a href="https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/eb48d7ab-a64a-4b99-b59d-72a34da60076/downloads/Calculator.zip?ver=1621722035246"><button class="btn">Download</button>**strong text**</a>
```

Comment: you can remove the strong text if u want the button to open the link only, like this: `<a href="https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/eb48d7ab-a64a-4b99-b59d-72a34da60076/downloads/Calculator.zip?ver=1621722035246"><button class="btn">Download</button></a>`